# Build Failed directory does not exist

Tags: apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, build, ant

I am new to Ant and dynamic web project. I created a build.xml and copied it from here [Tomcat example](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/build.xml.txt). I changed all the necessary directories.

But I still get an error.

This is the error message I get:

```
Buildfile: /Users/{myusername}/eclipse-workspace/JSF/build.xml
prepare:
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 5 source files to /Users/{myusername}/eclipse-workspace/JSF/build/WEB-INF/classes

BUILD FAILED
/Users/{myusername}/eclipse-workspace/JSF/build.xml:67: /Users/{myusername}/eclipse-workspace/JSF/usr/local/Tomcat/bin does not exist.

Total time: 649 milliseconds
```

And this is the line where the error occurs

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.home}" destdir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/classes" debug="${compile.debug}" deprecation="${compile.deprecation}" optimize="${compile.optimize}">
```

but i don't get why

Can you help me?

Comment: What's your `TOMCAT_HOME` env variable, if you've set it?

Comment: @vahdet i didn't set it

Comment: Have you executed this in verbose mode? like ant -v build.xml
Make sure ${src.home} and ${build.home} both are getting resolved.